# DataTable select won't fire for second time

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatables

I have 2 tables in my view where I select a row from `table1` and data return in `table2`

The problem is when i select second row it won't send ajax request while i can see click being triggered .

## Screenshots

`view`

[image: one]

`results`

[image: two]

## Code

`script`

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        // table 1
        $('.data_table').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            select    : true,
            language: {
                processing: '<span>Processing...</span>',
            },
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: '{{ route('schoolsIndexData') }}',
            columns: [
                { data: 'photo' },
                { data: 'name' },
                { data: 'type' },
            ],
            "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
                {
                    extend: 'copy',
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: [ 0, ':visible' ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    extend: 'excel',
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: ':visible'
                    }
                },
                {
                    extend: 'csv',
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: ':visible'
                    }
                },
                {
                    extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: [ 2, 3, 1 ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    extend: 'print',
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: ':visible'
                    }
                },
                'colvis'
            ]
        });

        // table 2
        $('.data_table tbody').on('click', 'tr', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var schoolId = $(this).attr('id');

            $('#teachers').DataTable({
                processing: true,
                destroy: true,
                retrieve:true,
                language: {
                    processing: '<span>Processing...</span>',
                },
                ajax: {
                    url: '{{url('dashboard/teacherIndexData')}}/'+schoolId,
                    type: "GET",
                    cache: true
                },
                columns: [
                    { data: 'id' },
                    { data: 'photo' },
                    { data: 'name' },
                    { data: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false },
                ],
                "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
                dom: 'Bfrtip',
                buttons: [
                    {
                        extend: 'copy',
                        exportOptions: {
                            columns: [ 0, ':visible' ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        extend: 'excel',
                        exportOptions: {
                            columns: ':visible'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        extend: 'csv',
                        exportOptions: {
                            columns: ':visible'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                        exportOptions: {
                            columns: [ 2, 3, 1 ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        extend: 'print',
                        exportOptions: {
                            columns: ':visible'
                        }
                    },
                    'colvis'
                ]
            });
            console.log(schoolId);  // result of this log is in screenshots above
        });
    });
</script>
```

## Question

Why can't I get my next clicks to send request to back-end? what should I do to fix this?

## Update

[Sample code](https://jsfiddle.net/robertnicjoo/dp78g56c/2/)

Comment: Do share a minimal snippet that reproduces your problem and I'll gladly take a look.

Comment: I'd suggest giving your tables unique IDs and you invoke the Datatable on clicking a row in any table...? That sort of looks quite messy TBH, I'd echo @IslamElshobokshy in suggesting developing a simple example on something like JSFiddle.

Comment: @annoyingmouse for giving id the thing is my `<tbody>` is printed by datatables so not sure how to give id an ID, also shared my code in update part hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved

I shouldn't have add `retrieve:true,` using `destroy: true,` is enough.

Comment: You don't need to destroy and recreate your table each button click. If you define your table as `const table = $('#teachers').DataTable({options});` (outside of your button click), you can then do `table.ajax.url('new-url-with-params').load()` inside your button click handler.